# messed up autostart, stuck booting into openbox. Help?

Tags: pi-3b+, boot-issues, chromium

I was trying to autoboot fullscreen into chromium and I improperly edited /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart with @chromium-browser --start-fullscreen https://{url}.com/

Now my pi boots into a black screen, right click shows openbox menu and I can't fix it.

I tried using the openbox terminal emulator but when I navigate to the autostart file it is empty.

Any assistance please?

Comment: Press [CTRL]+[ALT]+[F1] and you can login to a command line shell. From there you can undo the errors in your autostart file.

Answer (score 1):

If you press `Ctrl + Alt + F3` (or anything other than F7 ) you should get a command line login, then you can edit your files.

Alternatively you should be able to `ssh` to the command line.

You should generally avoid editing ANYTHING in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/` and make a local copy in `.config/lxsession/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  appreciate the help.  I tried logging in with pi and my set password and couldn't get in...(not sure why) and it was a newly re-imaged Buster sd card so I just re-re-imaged it.  i will need to learn how to ssh from my dual boot ubuntu machine but pw would have still been an issue.

re:  .config i was working on my second glass of wine and misread the doc I was working from. So raspberry and wine don't mix no matter what Boone's Farm says.